# HeatMap from folium.plugins doesn't show

Tags: python, heatmap, folium

I'm trying to draw a heatmap with folium.

My code:

```
import folium
from folium.plugins import HeatMap

base_location = (41.38861123888889, 2.1716497203703704)

m = folium.Map(
        location=base_location,
        zoom_start=13,
    )

# Some testing locs
locs = [
    [41.4257715, 2.1761088],
    [41.384546, 2.1638681],
    [41.3850111, 2.1658954],
    [41.3809043, 2.1734703],
    [41.3865159, 2.1709474],
    [41.3874418, 2.1706964],
    [41.3854827, 2.1700754],
    [41.3893763, 2.1728965],
    [41.3816256, 2.1748245],
    [41.3858352, 2.1943144]
]

HeatMap(locs).add_to(m)
m
```

[image: result map]

But my system returns a map without any heatmap layer. Why??

I also try to save the map into a html, and to present locs as list of tuples, but the result is the same.

Comment: This code works like a charm for me. What's your setup?

Comment: I'm on windows 7, with python 3.6.5, folium 0.10.0...

Ok, i tryed the same code on a Azure server, with a linux os, and dosen't work, but in another laptop it runs.... I think my browser is the problem, it's Google Chrome... suspicious

Comment: Is the code you provided here the code you actually ran? It should work perfectly as @stellasia said.

Comment: Yes, it is. And no, it doesn't work ... I am on a corporate computer with an limited chrome browser. I think it will be some kind of security limitation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved, I'v found that my company firewall block's github sources.

I just change heat_map.py:

```
    def render(self, **kwargs):
    super(HeatMap, self).render(**kwargs)

    figure = self.get_root()
    assert isinstance(figure, Figure), ('You cannot render this Element '
                                        'if it is not in a Figure.')

    figure.header.add_child(
        # Changed github source with any gitraw service alternative
        # JavascriptLink('https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.heat/dist/leaflet-heat.js'),  # noqa
        JavascriptLink('https://rawcdn.githack.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.heat/5885ec0ec2442876b67725c64dc537cb12c52c73/dist/leaflet-heat.js'),  # noqa
        name='leaflet-heat.js')
```